# LTspice Simulations with PCB parameter Tamb = 75 C vs on-board MOSFET working at 75 C comparisons

Tags: ltspice

I have built up LTspice simulation model for [DC2786A](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/DC2786A.html#eb-documentation?doc=DC2786A.pdf). I want to have the self heating effects of the MOSFETs and check how the efficiency of the converter is affected. But for the junction temperature to reach steady state it takes at least 1 minute, for which simulations need to run for days.

I want to know if by keeping the PCB parameter Tamb = 85 C do mean that I am considering the self heating characteristics of the MOSFET when working at ~85 C. In this way I want to compare the converter efficiency in lab with the simulated efficiency.

Comment: Thanks you @winny

Comment: I think you need to build your own thermal subcircuit for the MOSFETs if the manufacturer doesn't already provide one.  SPICE doesn't include self-heating effects on intrinsic device models.  All you can do by default is simulate the device at different temperatures by setting its `temp=X` instance parameter.  You can sweep this parameter but it will be static throughout each simulation run.